# useDomainAdminAccess creates error in Google Drive API using service account authentication

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I am creating a service to watch some of my Shared Drive folders on Google Drive. I am using a service account for authentication as this is a service running on a server. Here is my code snippet:

```
const { google } = require("googleapis");

const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
  keyFile: "./credentials.json",
  scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"],
});

const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });

drive.drives
  .list({ q: "name = Clients", useDomainAdminAccess: true })
  .then((files) => {
    console.log(files);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

If I leave the `list` method parameters empty, I get back a response with status code 200 and an empty list of drives as expected (as the service account does not own any shared drives). As soon as I add the use `useDomainAdminAccess: true` parameter, I get an error response as follows:

```
GaxiosError: Invalid Value
    at Gaxios._request (/Users/bteres/Projects/fw-docs/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:85:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async JWT.requestAsync (/Users/bteres/Projects/fw-docs/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:342:22) {
  response: {
    config: {
      url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/drives?q=name%20%3D%20Clients&useDomainAdminAccess=true',
      method: 'GET',
      userAgentDirectives: [Array],
      paramsSerializer: [Function],
      headers: [Object],
      params: [Object: null prototype],
      validateStatus: [Function],
      retry: true,
      responseType: 'json',
      retryConfig: [Object]
    },
    data: { error: [Object] },
    headers: {
      'alt-svc': 'h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-25=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"',
      'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0',
      connection: 'close',
      'content-encoding': 'gzip',
      'content-security-policy': "frame-ancestors 'self'",
      'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      date: 'Sun, 07 Jun 2020 10:43:54 GMT',
      expires: 'Sun, 07 Jun 2020 10:43:54 GMT',
      server: 'GSE',
      'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
      vary: 'Origin, X-Origin',
      'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
      'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
      'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block'
    },
    status: 400,
    statusText: 'Bad Request',
    request: {
      responseURL: 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/drives?q=name%20%3D%20Clients&useDomainAdminAccess=true'
    }
  },
  config: {
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/drives?q=name%20%3D%20Clients&useDomainAdminAccess=true',
    method: 'GET',
    userAgentDirectives: [ [Object] ],
    paramsSerializer: [Function],
    headers: {
      'x-goog-api-client': 'gdcl/4.2.1 gl-node/12.17.0 auth/6.0.1',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
      'User-Agent': 'google-api-nodejs-client/4.2.1 (gzip)',
      Authorization: 'REDACTED',
      Accept: 'application/json'
    },
    params: [Object: null prototype] {
      q: 'name = Clients',
      useDomainAdminAccess: true
    },
    validateStatus: [Function],
    retry: true,
    responseType: 'json',
    retryConfig: {
      currentRetryAttempt: 0,
      retry: 3,
      httpMethodsToRetry: [Array],
      noResponseRetries: 2,
      statusCodesToRetry: [Array]
    }
  },
  code: 400,
  errors: [
    {
      domain: 'global',
      reason: 'invalid',
      message: 'Invalid Value',
      locationType: 'parameter',
      location: 'q'
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried leaving that out and only using the `q` parameter and I get the same response. If I leave out the `q` parameter, same problem.

I have been at this for a couple of days and any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
I have already enabled domain-wide delegation for the service account as can be seen below.
[image: Service account]
I have also enabled this in my G-Suite admin API Management controls as seen below.
[image: G-Suite Admin API management]
Did I possibly get some of the config incorrect here?

Comment: I think the problem may be related with the use of a Service account. As stated in the documentation `useDomainAdminAccess` should be used by an account flagged as admin for said domain. Try to give such privilege to the service account or do the same request with an account that you know is admin and reach back to see if that works? otherwise your code seems completely fine

Comment: Thanks for the response @Raserhin. I have updated the question to show what I have already done in terms of domain-wide delegation settings. Did I maybe do something wrong? When I tried to use OAuth and my account (Super Admin), I got domain-wide results but still nothing for the service account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After hours of struggle and another nudge, I managed to figure this out. Google's API documentation is not so clear on this. Basically, you can use your service account but the service account need to impersonate a specific user, it is not by default an admin user in your domain even if you have all the configuration done.

So the easiest option I could figure out was to use google-auth's JWT credentials method as below:

```
const { google } = require("googleapis");

const credentials = require("./credentials.json");
const scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"];

const auth = new google.auth.JWT(
  credentials.client_email,
  null,
  credentials.private_key,
  scopes,
  "admin@domain.com"
);

const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });
```

After changing the auth method to this, the query above works as expected.